# Python Changes Object Data Inside List Syncronously With The Related Object

Tags: python, oop

```
class RandomData:



def __init__(self):

    self.id=0

def rand_prod(self):


    self.id+=1

    self.name,self.surname=unique_names_generator.get_random_name().split()

    self.address=real_random_address()

    self.birthday=datetime.date(randint(1950,2021),randint(1,12),randint(1,28))

    self.latitude=(18,16)

    self.longtitude=(18,16)



data_list=[]

current_rd=RandomData()

for i in range(5):

     current_rd.rand_prod()
     data_list.append(current_rd.__dict__)
```

I create a RandomData object and call the rand_prod() method inside the for loop, and in the loop I append this data to a list by saying objectname.**dict**,
but when I print the last list, all 5 dicts in the list have the data obtained in the last for loop. Every time I change the properties of the object, the old properties that I previously added in the list also change. What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

Comment: That `current_rd.__dict__` is one dictionary that you added to your list five times.

Comment: You need to make a copy of the dict. Your current code makes 5 copies of the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should really make a new object each time round the loop.

```py
data_list=[]

for i in range(5):
     current_rd=RandomData()
     current_rd.rand_prod()
     data_list.append(current_rd.__dict__)
```